# groupplots with multiple little bar charts has mystified me

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

I am trying to create a graphic as beautiful as the one attached.

My graphic has 3 columns and 6 rows so a 3x6 matrix.

Headaches:

- Issue 1: `ylabels` and `yticklabels` should only appear on the outermost y-axis--- called y edgeleft and not in every submatrix. The `xlabels` and `xticklabels` should only appear on the the uppermost x-axis called x edge top.
- Issue 2: As you can see from the sample the x-labels are very long.
- Issue 3: How to accommodate sub-barcharts which have negative values. Is it possible to have the middle line visible so that positive and negative bars are easily delineated?

This time I do have a MWE. Though its a mess. My apologies.

[image: Sample]
And here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table,usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\pgfplotsset{
    width=\textwidth,
}
\definecolor{forestgreen(web)}{rgb}{0.13, 0.55, 0.13}
\definecolor{uclagold}{rgb}{1.0, 0.7, 0.0}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
group name=my plots,
group size=3 by 6,
xlabels at=edge bottom,
ylabels at=edge left,
horizontal sep=0pt,
vertical sep=0pt,
/pgf/bar width=15pt},
width=5.5cm,
height=5.5cm,
    axis lines*=left,
    xbar,
     enlarge y limits  = 0.5,
    symbolic y coords={{Non-Poor}, {Moderately Poor}, {Extremely Poor}},
    yticklabels={Non-Poor, Moderately Poor, Extremely Poor},
    xtick=data,
    ylabel style={align=center}, 
    ylabel=A very long\\long\\text as a label,
    xlabel style={text width=2.5cm}, 
    xlabel=This is a long xlabel,
     xmajorgrids, tick align=inside,
        y axis line style={opacity=0},
        major grid style={draw=white},
        tickwidth=0pt,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=0.8, 
    point meta={x*100},
    nodes near coords={\tiny\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
    nodes near coords align={horizontal}
    ]
    \nextgroupplot
  \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue] coordinates{(0.22,{Non-Poor})  (0.35,{Moderately Poor}) (0.44,{Extremely Poor})};
   \nextgroupplot
  \addplot[draw=uclagold,fill=uclagold] coordinates{(0.39,{Non-Poor})  (0.28,{Moderately Poor}) (0.09,{Extremely Poor})};
  \nextgroupplot
  \addplot[draw=forestgreen(web),fill=forestgreen(web)] coordinates{(0.65,{Non-Poor})  (0.52,{Moderately Poor}) (0.20,{Extremely Poor})};
  \nextgroupplot
  \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue] coordinates{(0.18,{Non-Poor})  (0.27,{Moderately Poor}) (0.18,{Extremely Poor})};
   \nextgroupplot
  \addplot[draw=uclagold,fill=uclagold] coordinates{(0.13,{Non-Poor})  (0.10,{Moderately Poor}) (0.05,{Extremely Poor})};
  \nextgroupplot
  \addplot[draw=forestgreen(web),fill=forestgreen(web)] coordinates{(0.49,{Non-Poor})  (0.43,{Moderately Poor}) (0.17,{Extremely Poor})};  
\nextgroupplot
  \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue] coordinates{(0.38,{Non-Poor})  (0.35,{Moderately Poor}) (0.15,{Extremely Poor})};
   \nextgroupplot
  \addplot[draw=uclagold,fill=uclagold] coordinates{(0.05,{Non-Poor})  (0.08,{Moderately Poor}) (0.00,{Extremely Poor})};
  \nextgroupplot
  \addplot[draw=forestgreen(web),fill=forestgreen(web)] coordinates{(0.35,{Non-Poor})  (0.44,{Moderately Poor}) (0.10,{Extremely Poor})};  
\nextgroupplot
  \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue] coordinates{(0.42,{Non-Poor})  (0.43,{Moderately Poor}) (0.29,{Extremely Poor})};
   \nextgroupplot
  \addplot[draw=uclagold,fill=uclagold] coordinates{(0.14,{Non-Poor})  (0.13,{Moderately Poor}) (0.05,{Extremely Poor})};
  \nextgroupplot
  \addplot[draw=forestgreen(web),fill=forestgreen(web)] coordinates{(0.68,{Non-Poor})  (0.52,{Moderately Poor}) (0.13,{Extremely Poor})};  
\nextgroupplot
  \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue] coordinates{(0.04,{Non-Poor})  (0.34,{Moderately Poor}) (0.24,{Extremely Poor})};
   \nextgroupplot
  \addplot[draw=uclagold,fill=uclagold] coordinates{(0.48,{Non-Poor})  (0.37,{Moderately Poor}) (0.20,{Extremely Poor})};
  \nextgroupplot
  \addplot[draw=forestgreen(web),fill=forestgreen(web)] coordinates{(0.56,{Non-Poor})  (0.52,{Moderately Poor}) (0.35,{Extremely Poor})};  
\nextgroupplot
  \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue] coordinates{(0.50,{Non-Poor})  (0.44,{Moderately Poor}) (0.34,{Extremely Poor})};
   \nextgroupplot
  \addplot[draw=uclagold,fill=uclagold] coordinates{(0.40,{Non-Poor})  (0.31,{Moderately Poor}) (0.20,{Extremely Poor})};
  \nextgroupplot
  \addplot[draw=forestgreen(web),fill=forestgreen(web)] coordinates{(0.76,{Non-Poor})  (0.66,{Moderately Poor}) (0.42,{Extremely Poor})};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry its my first time. I am not exactly sure how to upload my MWE. Any help CarlaTex?

Comment: I've improved the formatting of your post. You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps,

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
%\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
%\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[table,usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\pgfplotsset{
    width=\textwidth,
}
\definecolor{forestgreen(web)}{rgb}{0.13, 0.55, 0.13}
\definecolor{uclagold}{rgb}{1.0, 0.7, 0.0}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}
  [
    group style=
    {
      group name=my plots,
      group size=3 by 6,
      %horizontal sep=0pt,
      vertical sep=0pt,
      /pgf/bar width=15pt,
      xticklabels at=edge top,
      yticklabels at=edge left,
      xlabels at=edge bottom,
      ylabels at=edge left,
    },
  % limits settings
    xmin=-.2,
    xmax=0.8, 
    width=5.5cm,
    height=5.5cm,
    enlarge y limits=0.5,
    axis lines*=left,
    xbar,
  % axis lines
    axis x line=top,
    axis line style={-},
    y axis line style={opacity=0},
    major grid style={draw=gray},
  % labels
    symbolic y coords={{Non-Poor}, {Moderately Poor}, {Extremely Poor}},
    ytick=data, %thanks to @Torbjørn T.
    ytick style={draw=none},
    ylabel style={align=center}, 
    ylabel=A very long\\long\\text as a label,
    xlabel=This is a long xlabel,
    xmajorgrids, 
    every axis x label/.style=
    {
      at={(rel axis cs:0.5,-.2)},
    },
  % ticks
    typeset ticklabels with strut,
    xtick distance = .2,
    tick align=inside,
  %nodes near coords
    nodes near coords={\tiny\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
    nodes near coords style={fill=white},
    nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    point meta={x*100},
  ]
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue] coordinates{(0.22,{Non-Poor})  (0.35,{Moderately Poor}) (0.44,{Extremely Poor})};
  \nextgroupplot
    %\addplot[draw=uclagold,fill=uclagold] coordinates{(0.39,{Non-Poor})  (0.28,{Moderately Poor}) (0.09,{Extremely Poor})};
    \addplot[draw=uclagold,fill=uclagold] coordinates{(0.39,{Non-Poor})  (-0.18,{Moderately Poor}) (0.09,{Extremely Poor})};
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot[draw=forestgreen(web),fill=forestgreen(web)] coordinates{(0.65,{Non-Poor})  (0.52,{Moderately Poor}) (0.20,{Extremely Poor})};
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue] coordinates{(0.18,{Non-Poor})  (0.27,{Moderately Poor}) (0.18,{Extremely Poor})};
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot[draw=uclagold,fill=uclagold] coordinates{(0.13,{Non-Poor})  (0.10,{Moderately Poor}) (0.05,{Extremely Poor})};
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot[draw=forestgreen(web),fill=forestgreen(web)] coordinates{(0.49,{Non-Poor})  (0.43,{Moderately Poor}) (0.17,{Extremely Poor})};  
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue] coordinates{(0.38,{Non-Poor})  (0.35,{Moderately Poor}) (0.15,{Extremely Poor})};
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot[draw=uclagold,fill=uclagold] coordinates{(0.05,{Non-Poor})  (0.08,{Moderately Poor}) (0.00,{Extremely Poor})};
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot[draw=forestgreen(web),fill=forestgreen(web)] coordinates{(0.35,{Non-Poor})  (0.44,{Moderately Poor}) (0.10,{Extremely Poor})};  
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue] coordinates{(0.42,{Non-Poor})  (0.43,{Moderately Poor}) (0.29,{Extremely Poor})};
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot[draw=uclagold,fill=uclagold] coordinates{(0.14,{Non-Poor})  (0.13,{Moderately Poor}) (0.05,{Extremely Poor})};
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot[draw=forestgreen(web),fill=forestgreen(web)] coordinates{(0.68,{Non-Poor})  (0.52,{Moderately Poor}) (0.13,{Extremely Poor})};  
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue] coordinates{(0.04,{Non-Poor})  (0.34,{Moderately Poor}) (0.24,{Extremely Poor})};
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot[draw=uclagold,fill=uclagold] coordinates{(0.48,{Non-Poor})  (0.37,{Moderately Poor}) (0.20,{Extremely Poor})};
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot[draw=forestgreen(web),fill=forestgreen(web)] coordinates{(0.56,{Non-Poor})  (0.52,{Moderately Poor}) (0.35,{Extremely Poor})};  
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue] coordinates{(0.50,{Non-Poor})  (0.44,{Moderately Poor}) (0.34,{Extremely Poor})};
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot[draw=uclagold,fill=uclagold] coordinates{(0.40,{Non-Poor})  (0.31,{Moderately Poor}) (0.20,{Extremely Poor})};
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot[draw=forestgreen(web),fill=forestgreen(web)] coordinates{(0.76,{Non-Poor})  (0.66,{Moderately Poor}) (0.42,{Extremely Poor})};
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Cheers,

Comment: I'd suggest `ytick=data` instead of `yticklabels={,,Non-Poor, Moderately Poor, Extremely Poor}`.

Comment: Thanks, that's better ; I overlooked this in the midst of everything !

Comment: Fantastic..I know, I know just couldn't resist. Seems a "tick"  would not reflect the brilliance of the answer and the greatness of Tex ecosystem.